# how to achieve text reflow in web page design

Tags: javascript, css

I want to make my web pages to have the property of text reflow, however I do not know how to achieve that. Is it a matter of css or javascript? For those who do not understand what I mean with text reflow, this is the automatic text wrapping in mobile devices, regardless the zoom, as to adjust the whole text in any screen width without having to move left or right.
Thank you

Comment: Hmmm... Seems like easy task for jQuery...

Comment: It sounds like you need to use the [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: HTML/CSS do(es) this "naturally" (@Bojangles comment will help a lot if like most webdevs you set a width to your pages). Just try to avoid things like `height: 500px` or `position: absolute` (for layout). Webdesign terms you can search for are: **`Responsive Web Design`** and `Mobile first`

Comment: Just make a simple web document: `<h1>This is a test</h1><p>Put a lot of text here</p>`, open it in a browser, resize the window and watch how the text automtically reflows. No CSS, no JavaScript! It's like magic!

Comment: I think the comments above are missing the point of the question, which is how to get text to wrap when zooming in on a mobile device. It's a good question, to which I'm not sure there's a satisfactory answer. You can prevent page zooming with `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`, but then that doesn't allow for scaling / zooming at all. I don't know if it's possible to allow for zooming in while keeping all content visible (as is possible on desktop browsers).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use the `word-wrap` property of CSS and set its value to break-word.

For example:

```
 <p style="word-wrap:break-word"> put your text here</p>
```